# How to check if json object key:value is not empty in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to check if my JSON key:value is not empty from mysql
Below is data :

```
ID |  usid   | catgval
:--|  :----- | :-----------------
1  |  7      | {"category":{"3":"48","9":"14","11":"16","8":"9"}}
2  |  7      | {"category":{"67":"7","83":"38","84":"23","85":"10"}}
3  |  7      | {"category":{"8":"","6":"5","9":"","11":""}}
```

I did below query to get JSON from above table :

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(`catgval`, '$.category') AS newval
FROM usersys;
```

which result as :

```
newval
{"3":"48","9":"14","11":"16","8":"9"}
{"67":"7","83":"38","84":"23","85":"10"}
{"8":"","6":"5","9":"","11":""}
```

But as seen in above 3 row values for 8,9,11 are empty.

Hence I need to check if any value is empty then result should come as below.

```
newval                                   | Status | Count
---------------------------------------------------------
{"3":"48","9":"14","11":"16","8":"9"}    | 0      | 0
{"67":"7","83":"38","84":"23","85":"10"} | 0      | 0
{"8":"","6":"5","9":"","11":""}          | 1      | 3
```

Please note above key:value can be anything as per user entry.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know which keys can be in there, then I suppose this might get quite difficult to do in SQL. I would do it in PHP afterwards.

Comment: Can you please suggest me same in php ?

Comment: Decode the JSON, loop over it, and increment your counter if the value is an empty string ...?

Comment: can you please help me in same ?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with, regarding something so basic?